# ES7 Map JSON adds square brackets

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I am using `core-js` for the Map collection, since it seems **ES7** `Map` has a Map to JSON functionality which does not exist in **ES6** `Map`.

```
(ES6): JSON.stringify(new Map().set('myKey1', 'val123').set('myKey2', 'val456')); => {}
```

Although ES 7 seems to add unnecessary square brackets to the key value pairs

```
Eg (ES7): JSON.stringify(new Map().set('myKey1', 'val123').set('myKey2', 'val456')); => [["myKey1","val123"],["myKey2","val456"]]
```

when I would expect this instead:

```
{"myKey1": "val123","myKey2":"val456"}
```

Please help!

**EDIT:**
I realised I posted a bad JSON, but that was just a typing error when writing the question.

The point is, beacause I am using TypeScript to create a new `Map` of **string** key -value pairs like

```
new Map<string, string>()
```

I would expect the JSON output of a such Map to be  `{"myKey1": "val123","myKey2":"val456"}` so I would ask for suggestions on how do I get the desired outcome.

Comment: `{"myKey1","val123","myKey2","val456"}` isn't valid JSON.

Comment: Your output is invalid JSON. Objects (`{}`) need to follow the `key: value` format. The ES7 output is the only way to serialize a `Map`: As keys can be arbitrary objects, the serialization can also be arbitrarily nested. So a mere string key wont work here, instead they went for a `[ key, value ]` format.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. The only time you've used a question mark is after a statement of fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the default map iterator is `.entries` which yields key-value pairs. If you want to use another iterator, you have to provide or program it, for example:

```js
function *flatEntries(map) {
    for (let [k, v] of map) {
        yield k;
        yield v;
    }
}


let m = new Map().set('myKey1', 'val123').set('myKey2', 'val456');
let s = JSON.stringify([...flatEntries(m)]);

console.log(s)
```